# BI Publisher administration API

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

Are there any SOAP/REST API available for BIP administration? I'm mostly interested in a possibility to define JDBC data source for reports.

Whole situation description:
For development purposes BI Publisher is run as Docker container. We have multiple environments (with separate databases), where some of them will have a BI Publisher instance. We would like to automate BI Publisher environment creation, so we need to dynamically define data source for BI Publisher reports, so that it would correspond to appropriate environment.

Answer (score 0):

No for datasources. But the createReport service takes a dynamic data model.

The server settings are actually set in .config files. You could write your own external webservices to modify these config files are restart the server.